# How do I display a randomly generated list in columns with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to determine how to display the following randomly generated list in columns? The code below generates a vertical display of quotes.

The goal is to be able to display quotes in rows of 4, not only vertically. How would I do this?

Current JS:

```
var my_res = _.sample([
'Quote 1', 
'Quote 2',
'Quote 3',
'Quote 4', 
'Quote 5',
'Quote 6'
], 5);

    var arr_len = my_res.length;
    var targ = document.getElementById('i_need_quotes_within_this');
    for(i=0; i<arr_len; i++){
        targ.innerHTML += "<q class=\"style\">"+my_res[i]+"</q><br/>"
    }
```

Current CSS:

```
.style{
  color: rgb 0, 0, 255;
  background-color: firebrick;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green ;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying style class to each quote. apply that to the div containing all of those.

CSS:

```
            .style{
            color: rgb 0, 0, 255;
            background-color: firebrick;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid green ;
            width: auto;
            //height: 100px;

            -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-column-count: 5; /* Firefox */
            column-count: 5;

            -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
            column-gap: 40px;

            -webkit-column-rule: 4px outset green; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-column-rule: 4px outset green; /* Firefox */
            column-rule: 4px outset green;               
          }
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="i_need_quotes_within_this" class="style">
        quote1<br/>
        quote2<br/>
        quote3<br/>
        quote4<br/>
        quote5<br/>
        quote6<br/>
        quote7<br/>
        quote8<br/>
        quote9<br/>
        quote10<br/>

    </div>
```